# How to create a new object in the unit tests project?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core

I have a class that uses interface. I would like to use the class itself in my unit test, but I don't know how to do it.

**My code:**

```
public class Store
{
    private readonly ICache _Cache;
    public CacheStore(ICache cache)
    {
        _Cache= cache;
    } 
}
```

How to use the CacheStore class now?

```
[Test]
public void test_method()
{
    var options = new CacheStore(??);
}
```

Comment: you will need to mock test implementation for `ICache`

Comment: What are you **actually** trying to do? This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Two choices:  -use moking libray as **Moq** or implement a **stub** in your test project (a fake class that implements ICache )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mock your ICache interface.

Say if you have store class is defined like this

```
public class Store
{
    private readonly ICache _Cache;

    public Store(ICache cache)
    {
         _Cache = cache;
    }
}
```

In your Unit Test, you have to create a Moq object of `ICache`

```
Mock<ICache> _icache = new Mock<ICache>();
```

You can create `Store` object using Moq object:

```
Store _s = new Store(_icache.Object);
```

After that, you can setup required fields using SetUp method of Moq.
If you are new Mocking, please refer to the following [link](https://www.codementor.io/copperstarconsulting/intro-to-unit-testing-c-code-with-nunit-and-moq-part-1-y2b9iv8iq).